# Numerical Summary of hh:mm:ss as a LateX Table

Tags: r, knitr, lubridate

So I have a variable of times (No dates) and I would like a table of a few basic statistics. I'm not sure why this is so difficult!

The following gives my almost what I want but the times are displayed in a decimal format. I would like them to be in hh:mm:ss format.

```
library(lubridate)
library(reporttools)

my.times <- seq(c(ISOdate(2000,3,20)), by = "5 sec", length.out = 10)

my.formatted.times <- data.frame(HappyFunTime = times(format(my.times, format="%H:%M:%S")))

tableDate(vars  = my.formatted.times,
          stats = c("n", "min", "max", "na") )
```

I am using knitR through RStudio if that makes any difference.

As always, thank you for your help!

Comment: R does not have any a time-only data type. It only has functions for date+time values. Lubridate does have a "Period" class that is a duration of time, but it's also meaningless unless added to a date value (for example adding 1 month to a date may result in a different total number of seconds depending in the month and time zone). The easiest thing to do would just be to add a sentinel date value to your times, do your arithmetic, and then format to look like a time again. Unfortunately it looks like the `tableDate` function is a hot mess and will not be easy to use this way.

Comment: hhhmmmm......Thank you for your response! 

Funny that this is so difficult. We just have data across multiple days, times, and locations, and I want to show the minimum and maximum time it was collected for each location, regardless of the date it was collected on.